# solr. what does it mean numfound?

Tags: java, solr

I try to understand solr official tutorial.

I make query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=*&fl=name,id
```

and see next response:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">125</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="fl">name,id</str>
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="q">*</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="28" start="0">
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

why is numfound equals 28 but doc number is 10?

Comment: Guessing here ... It gives you one page of results (the first ten docs) at a time?

Comment: how can I change this value?

Comment: See my answer on how to change your query to get "all" the data (or follow the links in @jro's answer, and figure it out from there...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change your query to

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=*&fl=name,id&rows=1000000
```

The `rows=` parameter specifies the number of results to return. With a value of 1000000 you will effectively get all the docs (not just the first 10, which is the default).

If you wanted to be a bit more careful, you could read the `numFound` parameter, then make multiple calls to return blocks of data with

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=*&fl=name,id&start=0
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=*&fl=name,id&start=10
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?indent=on&q=*&fl=name,id&start=20
```

This will return 10, 10, and 8 docs respectively.

Comment: I cannot understand link between {0 10 20} and {10 10 8}

Comment: You have 28 documents total. When you start at 0, you get the first 10. When you start at 10, you get the next 10. When you start at 20, there are only 8 left to the end - so you get all of them. Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks good answer , now able to understand why their is number difference

Answer (score 3):

numFound indicates the number of documents in the search index that matched your query. Solr only returns the specified number of documents in results, though. Without setting parameters,  defaults are used; everything is configurable, either through the query string or in query configuration (see solrconfig.xml).

Getting to those results is through paging parameters, specifically [start](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#start) and [rows](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#rows).

Comment: +1 for finding the links. I wrote an alternative answer for people who don't want to follow the links and figure it out from there...